# ¿Cómo pasar un callback hell a promesas?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, promesas, callback

Tengo esta código que es un *callback hell* que tengo que transformarlo en promesa o `async/await`
Lo estoy intentando con promesas, pero sin usar `promisify` u otros parecidos

Lo que pretendo hacer es igualar esas tres funciones a una variable tres funciones con `readdir`, `readFile` y `writeFile`

Pero hay dos parámetros que no acabo de entender de dónde salen y no se cómo meterlos en el `resolve`.

Uno, sería el files, que imagino hace referencia a la array del *path*, algo así `C:\\Users\\Otso\\Desktop\\prueba`, que lo recorre con el `foreach`, pero cuando tengo que pasar como parámetro files, no deduzco a que hace referencia, si tengo que pasarle la ruta  que me da *inbox* que sería `G:\Otso\0 Projecte TIC\0 IT Academy\3 Itinerario Nodejs\Patterns\inbox` o igualarla con variable serviría, porque pasar solo `inbox` como parámetro me da error.

Y el  otro, sería, el data que hay como parámetro de la función `reverseText`, que imagino hace referencia al *str*? o al texto que tiene que revertir, pero tampoco deduzco dónde está definido Aunque imagino que si saco la primera duda quizá se me esclarezca sola esta

Alguna sugerencia para el files y data?

El código es el siguiente

```js
const {
  readdir,
  readFile,
  writeFile
} = require("fs");

const {
  join
} = require("path");

const inbox = join(__dirname, "inbox");
const outbox = join(__dirname, "outbox");

const reverseText = str =>
  str
  .split("")
  .reverse()
  .join("");

// Read and reverse contents of text files in a directory
readdir(inbox, (error, files) => {
  if (error) return console.log("Error: Folder inaccessible");

  files.forEach(file => {
    readFile(join(inbox, file), "utf8", (error, data) => {
      if (error) return console.log("Error: File error");

      writeFile(join(outbox, file), reverseText(data), error => {
        if (error) return console.log("Error: File could not be saved!");
        console.log(`${file} was successfully saved in the outbox!`);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Que la estructura quedaría algo así:

```
const pruebaReadDir = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve

    reject("Error: Folder inaccessible")
  })
}

const pruebaReadFile = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve

    reject("Error: File error")
  })
}

const pruebaWriteFile = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve

    reject("Error: File could not be saved!")
  })
}

pruebaReadDir()
  .then
  .then
  .then
  .catch=(error=>console.log(error))
```

Comment: al decir: *o indicarme alguna web o video que me ayude a entenderlo mejor*, se interpreta como que estas pidiendo recomendaciones y puede que tu pregunta termine cerrada, recomiendo que elimines esa frase. Además hay un poco de inseguridad al decir: *Que la estructura quedaría algo así, **creo**:*

Comment: Gracias por las sugerencias Christian, realizados los cambios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para transformar en promesas las funciones que te provocan el callback hell, puedes hacer lo siguiente

```javascript
const pruebaReadDir = (inbox) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readdir(inbox, (error, files) => {
      if (error) reject("Error: Folder inaccessible");
      resolve(files);
    });
  });
}

const pruebaReadFile = (inbox, file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readFile(join(inbox, file), "utf8", (error, data) => { 
        if (error) reject("Error: File error");
        resolve(data);
    }); 
  });
}

const pruebaWriteFile = (outbox, file, data) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     writeFile(join(outbox, file), reverseText(data), error => {
        if (error) reject("Error: File could not be saved!");
        resolve();
      });
   });
}
```

Ahora para usarlos puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```javascript
const {
  readdir,
  readFile,
  writeFile
} = require("fs");

const {
  join
} = require("path");
const inbox = join(__dirname, "inbox");
const outbox = join(__dirname, "outbox");

async function main() { // aquí estaría la versión de tu código sin el callback hell (Usando aync y await
  let files = await pruebaReadDir(inbox);
  files.forEach(file => {
    let data = await pruebaReadFile(inbox, file);
    await pruebaWriteFile(outbox, file, data);
  }
}


const pruebaReadDir = (inbox) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readdir(inbox, (error, files) => {
      if (error) reject("Error: Folder inaccessible");
      resolve(files);
    });
  });
}

const pruebaReadFile = (inbox, file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readFile(join(inbox, file), "utf8", (error, data) => { 
        if (error) reject("Error: File error");
        resolve(data);
    }); 
  });
}

const pruebaWriteFile = (outbox, file, data) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     writeFile(join(outbox, file), reverseText(data), error => {
        if (error) reject("Error: File could not be saved!");
        resolve();
      });
   });
}
```

Comment: Gracias Andrés por tus aclaraciones . Sí, finalmente hice eso, tres funciones

Comment: Si la respuesta resolvió tu problema, por favor considera marcarla como aceptada y quizas darle upvote. Saludos